# Postgresql Query 'ANY' operator

Tags: sql, postgresql, any

I have this data where first column is called tcs_transportation code (Eg. BFKN, BOXNLW, BRNM1 etc) and the second is tcs_stages_code (e.g. OTMSC, AOTC, DOT, etc).
I want to get only those transportation codes which have only PSC as its stage and none other.

```
"BFKN"  "OTMSC"
"BFKN"  "AOTC"
"BFKN"  "DOT"
"BFKN"  "COI"
"BFKN"  "NOTS"
"BFKN"  "PSC"
"BOXNLW"    "OTMSC"
"BOXNLW"    "NOTS"
"BOXNLW"    "AOTC"
"BOXNLW"    "PSC"
"BOXNLW"    "DOT"
"BOXNLW"    "COI"
"BRNM1" "COI"
"BRNM1" "NOTS"
"BRNM1" "DOT"
"BRNM1" "PSC"
"BRNM1" "AOTC"
"BRNM1" "OTMSC"
"CMDU120P"  "OTMSC"
"CMDU120P"  "COI"
"CMDU120P"  "DOT"
"CMDU120P"  "PSC"
"CMDU120P"  "NOTS"
"CMDU120P"  "AOTC"
"CRU8W" "OTMSC"
"CRU8W" "COI"
"CRU8W" "PSC"
"CRU8W" "NOTS"
"CRU8W" "DOT"
"CRU8W" "AOTC"
"CRU8WDETCS"    "AOTC"
"LRA"   "NOTS"
"LRA"   "DOT"
"LRA"   "COI"
"LRA"   "AOTC"
"LRA"   "PSC"
"LRA"   "OTMSC"
"LRAAC" "PSC"
"LRAAC" "AOTC"
"LRAAC" "NOTS"
"LRAAC" "OTMSC"
"LRAAC" "COI"
"LRAAC" "DOT"
"LSLRDAA"   "PSC"
"LSLRDAA"   "NOTS"
"LSLRDAA"   "AOTC"
"LSLRDAA"   "COI"
"LSLRDAA"   "OTMSC"
"LWSCNAA"   "PSC"
"LWSCNAA"   "NOTS"
"LWSCNAA"   "OTMSC"
"LWSCNAA"   "COI"
"LWSCNAA"   "AOTC"
"LWSCZAA"   "NOTS"
"LWSCZAA"   "PSC"
"LWSCZAA"   "COI"
"LWSCZAA"   "OTMSC"
"LWSCZAA"   "AOTC"
"LWSCZAA"   "DOT"
"NMGHS" "COI"
"NMGHS" "NOTS"
"NMGHS" "AOTC"
"NMGHS" "PSC"
"NMGHS" "OTMSC"
"RCRV"  "PSC"
"RCRV"  "AOTC"
"RCRV"  "COI"
"RCRV"  "NOTS"
"RCRV"  "OTMSC"
"RCRV"  "DOT"
"RRV"   "NOTS"
"RRV"   "AOTC"
"RRV"   "DOT"
"RRV"   "PSC"
"RRV"   "COI"
"RRV"   "OTMSC"
"VPU"   "NOTS"
"VPU"   "AOTC"
"VPU"   "DOT"
"VPU"   "COI"
"VPU"   "PSC"
"VPU"   "OTMSC"
"WAG10" "PSC"
"WAG10" "AOTC"
"WAG10" "COI"
"WAG10" "DOT"
"WAG10" "NOTS"
"WAG9C" "COI"
"WAG9C" "PSC"
"WAG9C" "DOT"
"WAG9C" "OTMSC"
"WAG9C" "NOTS"
"WAG9C" "AOTC"
"WDAP5" "OTMSC"
"WDAP5" "AOTC"
"WDAP5" "COI"
"WDAP5" "DOT"
"WDAP5" "NOTS"
"WDAP5" "PSC"
```

I have tried to get it using the query but no success:

```sql
select tcs_transportation_code from(
'QUERY TO GET THE DATA SHOWN HERE'

) as old_query where tcs_stages_code <> ANY('AOTC', 'DOT', 'NOTS', 'COI','OTMSC')
```

I am new to PostgreSQL. Please help with suggestions.

Comment: You need to keep in mind that where conditions apply **per row**, you need to use `NOT EXISTS` to evaluate all rows for a tcs_transportation code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at all rows of a transportation code. This means you want to aggregate your data. Then see wehther there is only one entry for the transportation code and whether this entry is PSC. One method: Check that both the MIN and the MAX value equal PSC.

```
select tcs_transportation_code
from ( <QUERY TO GET THE DATA SHOWN HERE> ) as old_query
group by tcs_transportation_code
having min(tcs_stages_code) = 'PSC'
   and max(tcs_stages_code) = 'PSC'
order by tcs_transportation_code;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may work too :

```
SELECT *
FROM source_table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM source_table t2
                 WHERE t1.transportationcode = t2.transportationcode AND stages_code != 'PSC')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `any` in this case. Try this. It is longer but I hope self-explanatory.

```sql
with t as ( <QUERY TO GET THE DATA SHOWN HERE> ),
t2 as
(
 select tcs_transportation_code, array_agg(tcs_stages_code) arr
 from t
 group by tcs_transportation_code
)
select tcs_transportation_code 
from t2 
where arr = array['PSC'];
```

This approach is a bit more generic. You can use it to select transportation codes that have an exact *set* of stage codes too by parameterizing the `where` clause array. You may use other [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) in the `where` clause too.